# Отображение контента одной страницы на другой

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть страница http://lessons.lan, на которой нужно отобразить содержимое страницы другого сайта, используя ajax и js. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Используйте фреймы `<iframe src="link" />` http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe

Comment: Читайте про Cross Domain Requests, для ответа слишком много надо расписывать. Кроссдоменные запросы ограничены политикой безопасности браузера ["same-origin policy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) и если сервер Вам не отправит явное разрешение, то считать информацию с другого домена у Вас не получится без всяких костылей на типа фреймов, флешей, jsonp, cors proxy и даже в этом случае вы будете ограниченны в получаемых данных.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать перенаправления, самые основные ниже.

***В этом случае будет заменяться URL.***

**HTML** Redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://google.com'" />
```

**JavaScript** Redirect:

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
window.location.assign("http://google.com");
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

***В случаях ниже замены URL не будет.***

**iFrame Redirect:**

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

**PHP Redirect:**

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
?>
```